What is the origin of "Jingle Bells, Batman Smells?"
As of the time this question is being asked, it's the "holiday season," and with it comes the usual choruses of schoolyard children singing this variation of the classic song "Jingle Bells:"

Jingle bells Batman smells Robin laid an egg

According to Wikipedia, this version (which apparently has different regional variations) originated, or at least was popularized, in the 1960s. Is there a definitive original source for the song? Was it officially published by DC or did it start as a playground chant?

The Batmobile lost a wheel,  the Joker ran away

You try fighting crime all night in a bodysuit with a cowl and a cape, you'll smell too.

Is this on-topic here? Seems borderline at best. Like asking how Weird Al got the inspiration to write "Yoda" as a parody of "Lola". Yeah it's sci-fi adjacent, but only just.

@ToddWilcox - It's borderline, but attracting only upvotes and is quite interesting. I can't see any special reason we'd want to close it.

@Valorum - in the Animated Series episode I saw, I'm pretty sure it ended with "..and the Joker got away", immediately before the Christmas tree turned into a rocket and took off (with the Joker) through the asylum roof...

@Spratty - There are lots of regional variations.

@Valorum - indeed; it's just interesting that there's a specific call-out to the old children's rhyme in a "canon" source, and it only differs from what you heard by one word :-)

@PaulD.Waite As the Dark Knight parody says, "Really seals in the flavor!"

@Spratty In the first version I heard, line 3 was "Robin's gone away". I've also heard two different versions of lines 4/5/6. And one of those versions of line 6 was indeed "and the Joker got away!"

@Spratty "Crashing through the roof, in a one man open tree, bursting through I go, laughing all the waaaaaay, hahahaha!" - Mark Hamill's first Joker appereance in Batman TAS

@Valorum I remember it with the final line ending "AND Joker GOT away." (Yes I AM that old.)

No love for "Joker took ballet"? :D

There's a full song by Kamakazi where those few lines appear to be the chorus of a much longer version; and it confirms the correct version of the lyrics, The Joker got away.

Weirdly enough, Cracked.com seems to have the most rigorously researched history of the song. There have been a number of people who remembered it coming up in the mid-60s in California, possibly partially as a result of the Batman TV show, but the earliest citation is 1967 from the Lawton Constitution, source being an Army child in Belgium.


"American kiddos in Europe aren't completely divorced of the U.S. gimmicked tunes. Li'l Jana Montgomery, daughter of Maj. and Mrs. Ross D. Montgomery, formerly stationed at Fort Sil and now with MAAG headquarters in Brussels, Belgium, warbled this tune during the holidays:
"Jingle bells, Batman smells;
Robin rang away;
Batmobile lost a wheel -- and
Commissioner's stuck in sleigh."

As Clara Díaz Sanchez notes in a comment, Tom Scott did a survey of the remembered lyrics, and found not only a very wide variation of answers, but also that there is a distinct variation in the second line being "Robin laid an egg" or "Robin flew away" between the United States and the United Kingdom. He did not find direct evidence for his hypothesis that the appearance of the song in an episode of The Simpsons influenced the variation, but the statistics are suggestive of it.



Lastly, as others have noted, it looks like the first acknowledgement from DC Comics of the song was Joker singing it in the Batman the Animated Series episode "Christmas with the Joker".




https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22Batman+smells%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min:Jan+1_2+1965,cd_max:Dec+31_2+1970&num=10 - I can't find anything earlier than 1969 on Google Books

The Cracked article does also note that there's an earlier citation of the phrase "Btman smells" and the choice of Jingle Bells (other than the rhyme) may have in part been because, starting around the 1950s, it was a common choice for such parody ditties (admittedly, a lot of them being very racist), being well known and easy to sing.

Iona and Peter Opie's The Lore and Language of School Children is a fascinating read, but has no hits for this rhyme in a text search, so it should be after 1959 when the book was published.

There is an interesting account of the US vs UK versions of this song here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5u9JSnAAU4

That last line has an obscene amount of syllables.

@DonatelloSwansino - That's because you're saying it wrong. It's "C'mish-nus"

@Valorum Carn seez fishansy.

My understanding is the American/ UK robins are different bird species so why not different versification as well.

FWIW, @ClaraDíazSanchez and FuzzyBoots, I learned the "Robin laid an egg" version in early grade school circa 1980, growing up on the US east coast.  This was shortly after Matt Groening had started his self-published "Life in Hell" comic series in 1978, but well before the early work on "The Simpsons" in 1985. As such, I don't think "The Simpsons" could have been the origin of the "Robin laid an egg" variation in the lyrics, although they may have further popularized it.

I liked the subsequent scene in "Justice League Unlimited". The founding members turn themselves in to the Authorities. The head VIP asks "Where's Batman?". The Flash deadpans, "The Batmobile, it lost a wheel. The Joker got away." shrug "That's what I heard."

"Robin laid an egg" is a bit weird as I've never heard a rhyming couplet to go with it. The one I learned back in the sixties was Jingle Bells, Batman smells, Robin ran away. Batmobile, lost a wheel, and the Joker had to pay. It was the sort of thing made up by young kids in the playground and I was in South Africa so there was no TV to influence things.

In my version Robin did lay an egg but it was "the joker got away" as the last line.  Also, I grew in the midwest.
